# Styling buttons in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

a have a css script that styles a button and works perfectly on website and i'm now developing a mobile site for the website and when i use the css on a button on jquery mobile platform it doesn't seem to work like on the web page. it give a very long button and doesn't look pretty like on the website

```
<style>
    input.button-add {  background-image: url(../images/love.png); /* 16px x 16px */
        background-color: transparent; /* make the button transparent */
        background-repeat: no-repeat;  /* make the background image appear only once */
        background-position: 0px 0px;  /* equivalent to 'top left' */
        border: none;           /* assuming we don't want any borders */
        cursor: pointer;        /* make the cursor like hovering over an <a> element */
        height: 16px;           /* make this the size of your image */
        padding-left: 20px;     /* make text start to the right of the image */
        vertical-align: middle; /* align the text vertically centered */
    }
</style>

    <input name="button" type="submit" class="button-add" id="button" value="Love" />
```

Comment: Is the width problem in mobile? Then maybe put width in the css and see if that will help.

Comment: Your might need -webkit-appearance: none on iphone

Comment: agree with what @onetwo12 mentioned.  It is possibly responsive CSS queries that are overriding your custom styling.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/4svcsbgy/